# Index document maintaining spaces between words in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a text document in ElasticSearch 1.5 that may have words with many spaces in between them. I want to keep those spaces.  However, when I index the multiple spaces are removed (even though I have the field mapped as "index":"not_analyzed").  Is there a way to keep the spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Then it's something wrong with your mapping. Use `GET /index_name/_mapping` and search for the field that you are interested in (the one that you want to keep the spaces).

That field should have `"index":"not_analyzed"` in its definition. If it doesn't then you know something's wrong with the mapping.

Comment: Yes it is mapped correctly "origField":{"index":"not_analyzed","type":"string"}.  I take it from your answer that you would expect the spaces to remain?

Comment: Yes, indeed. How do you check that your field doesn't have the spaces? Can you show an example?